# 2 Drupal images in one machine

Tags: docker, drupal, docker-compose, content-management-system, drupal-8

**Description:**
im trying to find a way to run 2 Drupal containers using a docker compose on a single machine. I am currently having a problem to 'bind' the each Drupal storage into a separate location in MySQL.

Here's the following YAML file for Docker Compose:

```
---
version: '3'

services:
  drupal:
    build: ./
    image: geerlingguy/drupal:latest
    environment:
      DRUPAL_DATABASE_HOST: drupal-mysql
      DRUPAL_DATABASE_PORT: 3306
      DRUPAL_DATABASE_NAME: drupal
      DRUPAL_DATABASE_USERNAME: drupal
      DRUPAL_DATABASE_PASSWORD: drupal
      # Generate a salt with: `php -r "echo bin2hex(random_bytes(25));"`
      DRUPAL_HASH_SALT: db0de8a1556aa5348f87cfc950cd2c9641713d46e9412c8b05
    ports:
      #assign random port on the host
      - "80"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    restart: always
    # new
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    # Uncomment the volumes line and set to the local path of your Drupal
    # installation, if you need to work with a local codebase.
    volumes:
      # - ~/Sites/drupal-container:/var/www/html:rw,delegated
      - /Sites/drupal-container:/var/www/html:rw,delegated

  drupal2:
    build: ./
    image: geerlingguy/drupal:latest
    environment:
      DRUPAL_DATABASE_HOST: drupal-mysql
      DRUPAL_DATABASE_PORT: 3306
      DRUPAL_DATABASE_NAME: drupal
      DRUPAL_DATABASE_USERNAME: drupal
      DRUPAL_DATABASE_PASSWORD: drupal
      # Generate a salt with: `php -r "echo bin2hex(random_bytes(25));"`
      DRUPAL_HASH_SALT: db0de8a1556aa5348f87cfc950cd2c9641713d46e9412c8b05
    ports:
      #assign random port on the host
      - "80"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    restart: always
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - /Sites/drupal-container2:/var/www/html:rw,delegated

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: drupal-mysql
    # new
    volumes:
      - /Sites/drupal-container:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'yes'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: drupal
      MYSQL_USER: drupal
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: drupal
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

networks:
    # Define the default network
    # Services will use this automatically without having a networks key
    default:
        external:
            name: macvlan_net
```

FYI the network named macvlan_net is defined manually outside of the YAML file. (this allows me to access the Drupal container using IP address)

**Problem:**
when I run docker-compose up, I get 2 Drupal containers:
Drupal 1 - 132.177.14.1
Drupal 2 - 132.177.14.2

but once i run through the initial setup on Drupal 1, Drupal 2 seems to be mirroring the setup that I made also.

**Expected result:**
I should be greeted by the initial setup when visiting Drupal 2.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a single MySql container to house the databases for both Drupal instances(containers) you'll need to ensure that you're using unique database names during the Drupal install process. So during setup you could try:

- Drupal 1 -> Database Name: drupal_1_db
- Drupal 2 -> Database Name: drupal_2_db

Your other options are:

- Use table prefixes defined under advanced options instead of unique database names, but this isn't necessary unless you have a reason to keep both websites in a single database schema
- Use separate mysql containers for each Drupal instance